# How to correlate below given foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two for loops given below

```
foreach($result_access as $acc){
   $usr_access_id[] = $acc->id;
   $usraccess[] = $acc->rules;
}
```

**>  UPDATED**

```
     foreach($somearray as $someid){//Updated
        foreach($usraccess as $accessusr){
          if(in_array($someid,$usraccess)){
            $myid = ??;///Here i want the $usraccess associated $acc->id, how can I get that? 
          }
        }
      }
```

As you can see that I want the `$myid` get assigned with `$acc->id` which should be associated with the current `$usraccess` array

Comment: it comes from another foreach() loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sane solution:

```
foreach ($result_access as $acc) {
    if (in_array($someid, $acc->rules)) {
        $myid = $acc->id;
    }
}
```

The *insane* solution would be:

```
...

foreach($usraccess as $i => $accessusr){
  if(in_array($someid,$usraccess)){
    $myid = $usr_access_id[$i];
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really change anything about my answer though. :)

Comment: Thanks I Have combined ur solution and @Tudor solution to get my output and its working... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
foreach($result_access as $acc){
   $usr_access_id[] = $acc->id;
   $usraccess[ $acc->id ] = $acc->rules;
}

foreach($usraccess as $accessusr){
  if(in_array($someid,$usraccess)){
    $myid = $usraccess[ $someid ] ;///Here i want the $usraccess associated $acc->id, how can I get that? 
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for incomplete information pls find the updated question.... Also I am +1'ing your answer because it has been downvoted by someone due to my incomplete information.. Please re-view my question

Comment: Thanks I Have combined ur solution and @deceze solution to get my pitput and its working... Thanks again